# ND4J NoAvailableBackendException despite following all documentation steps

Tags: java, maven, deeplearning4j, nd4j, spigot

I have an annoying issue with ND4J while attempting to implement deeplearning4j into a project. As the title already says, it is a NoAvailableBackendException. I am getting this error with maven,
the full pom.xml is [here](https://pastebin.com/pgVRLCuy).
The stacktrace is [here](https://pastebin.com/1nz4cu6z).

The only thing I can think of that might have an effect is the fact that I am attempting to run this on a minecraft server. I do not quite know how to account for this or how to solve this issue if this is the cause.

I have attempted to use the maven import for nd4j;

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

In my IDE this does not give any errors, and it correctly packages.

I have the NoAvailableBackendException when using the packaged jar. I have followed all the troubleshooting steps the documentation offers:

- You haven't configured an ND4J backend at all.
  It is in maven without any issues
- You have a jar file that doesn't contain a backend for your platform.
  I am importing the nd4j-native-platform, the nd4j-native also does not give a different result.
- You have a jar file that doesn't contain service loader files.
  I have decompiled the packaged jar, it contains the necessary service loader files according to the documentation.

I have also attempted to use a different version of nd4j (and of course matching it with deeplearning4j-core). Also to no avail.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using for your OS? If you're using a mac arm instance that will not work with nd4j-native-platform.

Comment: @AdamGibson I am using default windows 11. I don't believe it's an unsupported CPU either as im just using an intel I7 11th gen. That being said i've also tried using cuda which gives the same error.

Comment: Make sure you're using an uber jar then. We have an example with the maven-shade-plugin. You never posted your configuration for that but if it works in your IDE there is no reason it shouldn't work if packaged propelry.